# Spotify Connect API for wireless speakers

Tags: api, spotify

Is the new Spotify Connect (for wireless speakers) API available for download? Any idees how they implemented it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, there isn't a public API for Spotify Connect. Keep an eye out on the Spotify Developer Website for any announcements that might be made.

Comment: Vote (give kudos) to this idea on the Spotify Community for a public API for Spotify Connect. http://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-Ideas/Publish-the-Spotify-Connect-Wireless-speaker-API/idi-p/520890

Comment: More than two years later, still no word about an updated libspotify with Connect support. Instead, they deprecated it, just like they did with apps, and the Web API doesn't have endpoints to control Spotify clients (you can't even figure out what song is currently playing...)

Answer (score 0):

There has been some reverse engineering going on. I can't give you the project names (forgot) but you might wanna hit their sites to check the progress.

From what I've read it's suppose to be fully reverse engineered.

Comment: Probably this one: http://divideoverflow.com/2014/08/reversing-spotify-connect/ but also see the links to closely related projects in the comments.